# Register ApplicationUserManager using Simple Injector

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, owin, simple-injector

How will I fix the error below when trying to run the project.

> The constructor of type ApplicationUserManager contains the parameter
>   with name 'store' and type `IUserStore<ApplicationUser>` that is not
>   registered. Please ensure `IUserStore<ApplicationUser>` is registered,
>   or change the constructor of ApplicationUserManager.

Below is my Identity Config

```
// Configure the user management application used in this application. 
// UserManager defined in ASP.NET Identity and is used in the application.
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(
        IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(
            new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        // Set the validation logic usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true,
        };

        // Set the password validation logic
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        // Set default values ​​for user lock
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

        // Record authentication providers in two phases. 
        // This application uses the steps Phone & Email to receive a code
        // to check the user
        // You can write your own provider and connect here .
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("phone code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            Subject = "Security code",
            BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider =
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(
                    dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
    }
}
```

and below is my Account controller with its corresponding constructor parameters. I've also removed the empty constructor since multiple constructor is not supported in simple injector and said to be anti pattern.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    //public AccountController()
    //{
    //}

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
    }

    public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _signInManager = value;
        }
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // No errors account login for the account lockout
        // To allow password errors trigger lock the account , switch to shouldLockout : true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username/password");
                return View(model);
        }
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email,
                Profile = new Profile
                {
                    EmployeeID = model.EmployeeID,
                    FirstName = model.FirstName,
                    LastName = model.LastName,
                    MiddleName = model.MiddleName
                }
            };

            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                // For more information about enabling confirmation and account password reset , visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send email with this link
                // String code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync ( user.Id ) ;
                // Var callbackUrl = Url.Action ( " Confirmemail " , "Account ", new { userId = user.Id , code = code} , protocol : Request.Url.Scheme ) ;
                // Await UserManager.SendEmailAsync ( user.Id , "Confirm Account" , " To confirm the account, click <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\"> here </a> ");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we reach this point , it is that it was an error and re- display the form
        return View(model);
    }

    private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
    {
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
        }
    }

    private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

Below is my SimpleInjector config

```
// Create the container as usual.
var container = new Container();
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();

// Register services
Config.RegisterContainer(container);

// This is an extension method from the integration package.
container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

// This is an extension method from the integration package as well.
container.RegisterMvcIntegratedFilterProvider();

// This will register services
Config.RegisterContainer(container);

container.Verify();

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
```

Comment: Try registering `IUserStore<ApplicationUser>`.

Comment: And have you looked at [this information](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions/564822) that the [documentation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration.html) refers to?