# Simple Injector Account Controller dependencies issue in Asp.Net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, simple-injector

In my Asp.Net Web API application I am using Simple Injector as IoC container. It's resolving the dependencies of other controllers. But I am having problems with the dependencies of default AccountController.

```
private static void ConfigureTypes(Container container)
{
    container.Register<Data.Contracts.Repositories.IProfileRepository,
        Data.Repositories.ProfileRepository>(Lifestyle.Transient);
}

public static void Configure()
{
    var container = new Container();
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebApiRequestLifestyle();
    ConfigureTypes(container);
    var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
    container.RegisterWebApiControllers(config);

    container.Verify();
    config.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
}
```

What should I do to resolve the dependencies of AccountController. Here are AccountController's default and parameterized constructors:

```
public AccountController()
{
}

public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager,
    ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> accessTokenFormat)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
    AccessTokenFormat = accessTokenFormat;
}
```

Comment: Is the ApplicationUserManager class an interface? If not, create an interface of it and register the type in the ConfigureTypes() method

Comment: AccountController is the absolute crap that is generated for you by a Visual Studio template. It's stuffed with bad practices, SOLID violations and amti-patterns. A great way to teach developers wrong things. Ideally uou should get rid of it or refactor it, but to get your application running, judt remove the overloaded constructor.

Comment: Many thanks @Steven, I have removed the overloaded constructor and it worked for me. But how can I refactor this? Because in future I have to inject dependencies in AccountController (may be of repository).

Comment: There's an old description on Codeplex about the [Identity Framework template](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions/564822) that I think is still relevant.

Comment: Right, I am checking it. Thanks again.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36356431/3294832

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37085776/3294832

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28948205/264697